# What exactly the debug assert will do in release build?

Tags: c++

My application behaves strange in release build when handling Chinese characters(wide). 
I have below line which throw  debug assert during debug mode:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace), str.end());
```

(Where str is std::wstring)
This line throw the assert when in debug mode. I know this is because **isspace** cannot handle wide char. Instead of **isspace**, I have to use **iswspace**.

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace), str.end());

            if (!str.empty())
            { // add str to GUI }
```

If I press '*Ignore*' in the debug assert, the **str** is added to the GUI properly.
But during release mode, the **str** is not added to GUI.

But if I use **iswspace**, the **str** is added to the GUI properly without making any change to my add to GUI logic.

Whats more strange is that some of the Chinese characters are added properly to the GUI during release mode also.
For example, str is added to GUI when it is **L"左"**. But not added to GUI when it is **L"右"**.

Did any one had this issue?

My understanding was in release mode, the debug asserts will not be considered and will work similar to '*Ignore*'.

Edit:

I debugged it further(in release). Looks like somehow it is not going inside if(!str.empty()) in the case of **L"右"**. But the visual studio debugger still shows L"右" inside str when it hit the break-point at the if condition.

Edit 2:
I added `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` above the str.erase line.
Now it works exactly same in debug and release case and text is added to the GUI.

Here is an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::wstring str1 = L"左";
    std::wstring str2 = L"右";
    str1.erase(std::remove_if(str1.begin(), str1.end(), isspace), str1.end());
    if (!str1.empty())
    {
        std::wcout << L"str1 not empty\n";
    }
    str2.erase(std::remove_if(str2.begin(), str2.end(), isspace), str2.end());
    if (!str2.empty())
    {
        std::wcout << L"str2 not empty\n";
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This print only "str1 not empty".

Comment: Ignoring a firing assert will most likely cause undefined behaviour in Release mode though. Make sure everything works in Debug before compiling for Release.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding the issue at hand. `assert` might not be the only difference; it's common for the Visual C++ libraries to have more extensive debug checks beyond a simple assert.

Comment: Seeing the text of the assertion would be nice, as would be an idea of the type of `str`. Because using `iswspace` on a `std::basic_string<char>` doesn't really work either. (Generally speaking, if you're doing Unicode, you should be using [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), as the standard is rather ill equipped for Unicode handling, even the newer versions fall rather short of "getting it right".) Could you perhaps come up with a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Good point from @DevSolar. To name just a common example: storing an UTF-8 string in `std::basic_string<char>`  is possible, but single code points will take multiple bytes. Multi-byte characters are **not** wide characters.

Comment: @MSalters More importantly, isspace() et al. are locale-dependent (and support of those locales is depending on the installation). Where things *completely* fall apart is toupper() / tolower(), comparisons / string normalization etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited the question and added further details. As I mentioned, str became empty in the case of 右. But I have no idea how it is happening.

Comment: @Jake: `L"..."` is a wide string literal. Depending on the (implementation-defined) encoding, a wide character from such a literal could include null bytes. If you pass that to a `std::basic_string<char>`, that null byte could be interpreted as end-of-string. I think it's high time for a [mcve], because right now we're all just guessing.

Comment: @DevSolar i have added an example.

Comment: Retracted close vote / downvote. Also removed the visual-c++ tag, as Linux / GCC displays identical behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Macro `assert` does nothing in release mode and will be ignored.

> If NDEBUG is defined as a macro name at the point in the source code
>   where  is included, then assert does nothing <sup>[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/assert.html),[2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)</sup>.

However, just ignoring the assertion doesn't solve the issue. Make your code work in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding was in release mode, the debug asserts will not be considered and will work similar to 'Ignore'.

Yes, but you're ignoring *undefined behaviour*, because you're passing out-of-range values to `isspace`.

Read [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) for the features and functions that you use:

> The behavior is undefined if the value of `ch` is not representable as `unsigned char` and is not equal to `EOF`.

Really, you should not be using `isspace` for this. Use a library that supports whatever encoding you're using (UTF-8? UTF-16?)

Answer (score 1):

Use [iswspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswspace) (and its wide-char brethren) for wide strings:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::wstring str1 = L"左";
    std::wstring str2 = L"右";
    str1.erase(std::remove_if(str1.begin(), str1.end(), iswspace), str1.end());
    if (!str1.empty())
    {
        std::wcout << L"str1 not empty\n";
    }
    str2.erase(std::remove_if(str2.begin(), str2.end(), iswspace), str2.end());
    if (!str2.empty())
    {
        std::wcout << L"str2 not empty\n";
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
str1 not empty
str2 not empty
```

Whether the `isspace` version "worked" or did not "work" in release mode or debug mode is a red herring, as you have been invoking *undefined behavior*:

[CppReference.com on isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), emphasis mine:

> The **behavior is undefined** if the value of ch is not representable as `unsigned char` and is not equal to `EOF`.

Comment: If you are going to do "real" text processing on Unicode strings, I strongly suggest [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) over anything the standard library gives you, because the standard is ill-equipped for handling Unicode correctly. String comparisons, normalization, tokenization, whatever -- as soon as you're going to actually care what is in those strings, you should use a library that actually *knows* about Unicode, and is equipped to handle its intricacies. I don't say ICU is easy or comfortable, but it is *capable*.

Comment: Agree with you. As I mentioned initially in the question. I have no issues when I am using iswspace. But my main concern was how the str become empty?!. Also once I added `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` it just works fine in release also.

Comment: @Jake "Undefined behavior" means, undefined. The computer might empty that string, it might water your plants or it might turn off your refridgerator. Don't bother trying to find out, because any answer would be specific to your current implementation, and would not tell you anything useful at all. It's a wasted effort, IMHO.